# Custom Taxonomy Breaks Pages

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error

I have a custom taxonomy called 'industry' that I want to use on custom post type 'website-design'. It works on the intended post type, but other pages are broken. I changed the 404 template as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645721/wordpress-taxonomy-causing-pages-to-404), and discovered this in the first part of the print_r when I try to go to the /about page:

```
WP_Query Object (
[query] => Array
(
    [industry] => about
)
[query_vars] => Array
(
    [industry] => about

...other parameters

[taxonomy] => industry

...other parameters

[tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
    (
        [queries] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => industry
                        [terms] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => about
                            )
```

As you can see, the custom taxonomy is getting inserted into the query. The code that declares the custom taxonomy is below:

```
function create_industry_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
            'name'              => 'Industries Serviced',
            'singular_name'     => 'Industry Serviced',
            'search_items'      => 'Search Industries Serviced',
            'all_items'         => 'All Industries Serviced',
            'parent_item'       => 'Parent Industry',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Industry:',
            'edit_item'         => 'Edit Industry',
            'update_item'       => 'Update Industry',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Industry',
            'new_item_name'     => 'New Industry Name',
        );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'rewrite'           => array(
            'slug' => 'industry',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
        'has_archive' => 'industries'
    );
    register_taxonomy('industry', array('website-design'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_industry_taxonomy', 0);
```

How do I continue to use this taxonomy without it breaking other pages?

Comment: Might not be the issue, but there is no such argument as `has_archive` for custom taxonomies.

Comment: I added that to test something I saw elsewhere - forgot to take it out. I removed it now, but it's not the problem.

Comment: there's nothing in the code you've posted that would cause this, a copy/paste of it into a default theme doesn't break pages. have you flushed permalinks each time you've made any changes?

Answer (score 1):

Create file called `taxonomy-industry.php` and copy your `archive.php` into it.

I faced the same proplem with my site and that solution worked for me.
Hope it works for you

Comment: If the problem pops up again, I'll try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*The issue appears to have resolved itself*

I had some custom permalink function rewriting `%industry%`, which I had tested and verified wasn't the problem. I changed its code and changed it back again, and the site works as expected now. I'm confused, but mostly satisfied.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer